# remotely executing multiple shell commands including "df -h" using root user in python

Tags: python, shell

I want to do the following thing  :

```
    if condition:
            cmd="ssh machine1 && sudo su - && df -h PathThatRequiresRootPriv | grep ..."

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,env=os.environ)
    (out_space,err) = proc.communicate()
    if err: 
            print err
            log.warning('%s',err)
            exit(1)
```

But i am clearly missing something because the program doesn't do anything.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by "doesn't do  anything"?

Comment: BTW  have you considered [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html) or [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)?

Comment: A wild guess about your command is that by chaining your commands with `&&`, they're not embedded (`sudo` runs after `ssh` terminates, `df` runs after `sudo` terminates, i-e after it's closed).
I'd rather suggest to make something like this :
`ssh machine1 sudo sh -c "df -h PathThatRequiresRootPriv | grep ..."`

(Assuming you found a way to automatically handle sudo authentication. this for instance causes a `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` if I try this raw command with my own machine)

Answer (score 0):

You are building commands in the form `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`. The 3 commands are executed one at a time **on the local machine** unless one of them return false. And from your title it is not what you expect... And the construct `sudo su -` will act the same and expect its commands from its own standard input and not from the next command.

The correct way here would be:

```
if condition:
    loc_cmd="ssh machine1"
    remcmd="sudo -i 'df -h PathThatRequiresRootPriv | grep ...'"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(loc_cmd,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,env=os.environ)
    (out_space,err) = proc.communicate(rem_cmd)
```

Say differently, you should only execute `ssh` on the local machine, pass `sudo -i` to the remote as a request to execute a command after simulating an initial login, and finally pass the pipeline as the parameter to `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you guys for theses suggestions !! I will try them and give you some feedback

Comment: about this line :  remcmd="sudo -i 'df -h PathThatRequiresRootPriv | grep ...'"
Will it  prompt me for entering the password  ? or do i need to add an extra line of code ?

Comment: @Pydev_2017: all depends how `sudo` has been configured. It **can** be configured to not ask a password, but by default (for security reasons) it does ask for one.

Answer (score 0):

You must look [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) - if you want use python
or [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/)

in fabric you can do different things on remote server like this:

```
from fabric.api import *

def check_disk_space(username, passw='none'):
    host = '%s@%s' % (env.user, env.host)
    env.passwords[host] = 'rootPass'
    # run from user
    run('df -h')
    # run from sudo
    sudo('df -h')

host='anyuser@10.10.10.101'
execute(check_disk_space, hosts=[host], username='anyuser', passw='')
```

Both support 'become' methods for execute remote commands through sudo

Comment: Hi , The problem with this solution is it exposes the root pass in plain text. I was rather looking for an interactive prompt of the password.  
Plus i am working in a production environment. The sys admin have refused to install fabric api . Do you see another way of doing the same thing ?
thank you in advance